# Mongoose Schema set an expires on field to delete document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete the document after 3 min it's been created. The field that defines the moment the document is created is expiresAt. This is the set up I have thus far. The document does not delete after 3 min as it should.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const PostsAmountsTimeframesSchema = new Schema({
  posts_amounts_timeframe: Number,
  expireAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: new Date()
  },
  userid: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
  },
})



PostsAmountsTimeframesSchema.index( { expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 180 } )

const PostsAmountsTimeframes = mongoose.model('PostsAmountsTimeframes', PostsAmountsTimeframesSchema)

module.exports = PostsAmountsTimeframes
```

Also tried

```
  expireAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: new Date(),
      expires: 180,
  }
```

same result.

PS: this is how the document is created on the server:

```
PostsAmountsTimeframes.create({
      userid: req.session.userId,
      posts_amounts_timeframe: req.session.posts_amounts_timeframe,
      // expireAt: d
  }, (error, postsamountstimeframes) => {
      console.log(error)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently have to create an TTL index using mongoose (cf. [gist](https://gist.github.com/boly38/2d3ead05b2491924ec97ac4d18a86528)). I didn't play with "default" option, but I think that your example should work

```
expireAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date(),
    expires: 180,
}
```

This code with "expires" will create for you a mongo TTL index with `"expireAfterSeconds" : 180` which is what you want to achieve.

Mongo TTL index will consider that the document is expired after `expireAt` value + `expireAfterSeconds` seconds.

One point you didn't talk about is the way mongo will finaly remove the expired entries : the background mongo job will takes between 0 and 60 seconds to detect and remove them: cf [mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#timing-of-the-delete-operation) :

> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the period between the expiration of the document and the running of the background task.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

- Delete entire collection
- Delete all indexes you have on the collection
- Change code to this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
//Create empty Schema object?
const Schema = mongoose.Schema


//Models are defined through the Schema interface
//Models define collections
const PostsAmountsTimeframesSchema = new Schema({
  posts_amounts_timeframe: Number,
  expireAt: {
      type: Date,
  },
  userid: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
  },
})

PostsAmountsTimeframesSchema.index({ expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });
//Access the database my_database via mongoose.model.
//The first argument: The name of the collection the model is for.
//Apply the model to the collection?
const PostsAmountsTimeframes = mongoose.model('PostsAmountsTimeframes', PostsAmountsTimeframesSchema)
//Export User variable to other files
module.exports = PostsAmountsTimeframes
```

Use this to create entry. I used 3 min after current date to expire collection.

```
  var d = new Date()
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()+3);
  var r = new Date(d)

    PostsAmountsTimeframes.create({
      userid: req.session.userId,
      posts_amounts_timeframe: req.session.posts_amounts_timeframe,
      expireAt: r
    }, (error, postsamountstimeframes) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

- Close mongosh
- Close Mongo Compass
- Rebuild project
- Rerun project
- Create an entry and Bam! It will auto delete itself upon creation of
  an entry.

There should be a way to do same thing with expires TTL. Working on that method currently!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const yourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  expireAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now() + (1000*60*60*24) // for 1 day
  }
})
```

Note: 1000 is 1 second and the default is the actual value of when it expires

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
const PostsAmountsTimeframesSchema = new Schema({
  posts_amounts_timeframe: Number,
  expireAt: {
      type: Date,
      expires: "3m", default: Date.now
  },
  userid: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
  },
})
```

Comment: No luck there. It's soo weirdly persistent does not delete.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the default value, with the default set to `Date.now`, it'll create a document that expires immediately.

```
"createdAt": "2023-06-17T15:14:01.109Z",
"expireAt": "2023-06-17T15:14:01.109Z",
"otp": "61046",
"updatedAt": "2023-06-17T15:14:01.109Z"
```

to fix this set the default date to be the expiration date, for example if the exipiration date is 30 minutes, set the default to current date + 30 minutes.

```
const OTPSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IOTP>({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  otp: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  expireAt: { type: Date, default: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3 /* expires after 3 minutes */ * 60000) }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```